# redirect when user is connected to facebook/google using Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, routes

i need to redirect user when he successefully connected to facebook or google.
THis is my route :

```
/*******************GOOGLE AUTH ROUTES********************* */
// auth with google+
router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    ]
}));
// callback route for google to redirect to
// hand control to passport to use code to grab profile info
router.get('/auth/google/callback*', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
    resultats = {
        "success": true,
        "message": 'SUCCESS',
        "result": req.user
    }
    res.json(resultats);
});
/*******************END GOOGLE AUTH********************* */
```

THis is my links (fb/google) :

```
 <div className="rs-btn">
                                    <a href={`${API}/auth/facebook`} target="_blank"className="btn facebook">
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookF} />
                                    </a>
                                    <a href={`${API}/auth/google`} target="_blank"className="btn google">
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGoogle} />
                                    </a>
                                </div>
```

And finally my config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    jwtsecret : "fatboardauth",
    session : {
        cookieKey : "thisisthefatboardK2019eH67882019"
    },
    oauth : {
        facebook : {
            clientID : 737996303314074,
            clientSecret : "06a5efdc93ebe7b84567874e4438d44d",
            callbackURL : "http://localhost:3001/auth/facebook/callback"
        },
        google : {
            clientID : "8216500008636-529u2au433fk80los8dtl841mvlab15q.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            clientSecret : "XB7gZyHUKYGJFkZgo-YvITtDI",
            redirect : "http://localhost:3001/auth/google/callback"
        }
    },
    supportemail : "fatboarrestaurant@gmail.com",
    gmailPSW : "myapp123!",
    secretKey : "c2VjcmV0S2DFGBBN?ZmF0Ym9hcjIwMTk=",
    schemes : 'http://',
};
```

when the user is connected in google for example, i have this in my browser :

```
{"success":true,"message":"SUCCESS","result":{"google":{"id":"112886936395081056197","email":"meryem.achemlal@gmail.com","name":"Achemlal Meryem"},"prenom":"Mem","nom":"Ach","tel":null,"dateCreation":"2019-11-13T18:45:58.69Z","datenaissance":null,"resetpasswordtoken":null,"resetpasswordexpires":null,"role":"user","enable":true,"_id":"5dcc4f7jh68861887ac259a","email":"mem.ache@gmail.com","__v":0}}
```

but what i want is that user redirected into homepage.
Haw can i do that with react ?

THank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `res.redirect('/path')`.

```
router.get('/auth/google/callback*', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
    resultats = {
        "success": true,
        "message": 'SUCCESS',
        "result": req.user
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: hello thanks for your answer, how can i do that in front (in my component) insteaed of routes please ?

Comment: `window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";` for client side javascript.

Comment: i should make a click function for that in the <a>.. </a> right ?

Comment: i made this, but it doesn't work : 

<a onClick={window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000"} href={`${API}/auth/google`} target="_blank"className="btn google">
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGoogle} />
                                    </a>